# Why does a console log show different information about an HTML element?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, event-handling, interactive

```
const myImage = document.getElementById('myImage')! as HTMLImageElement;
console.log('first log: ', myImage)

myImage.addEventListener('load',() =>{
    console.log('second log:', myImage)
})
```

[image: browser console]

I don't think it's anything to do wqith '! as HTMLImageElement' or typescript as I've experience this is vanilla JS and it's pretty annoything whel trying to work with the dom. I don't know what I need to do to consistently get it to load a certain way

**edit: I want to know if theres a consistant way to should the DOM element in a particular way; either as an object (first log) or the second version log. Sometimes, I'm trying to get access to the properties of a DOM element so I can do something with it in Javascript... so I console.log it to see what's available to me but in those desparate times, it will log like the second log, it won't show me what properties I have to my disposal.

The question as least to me is simple, how do I get the log to always show the methods of any DOM element (like in log one). OR consistantly show like in the second log...

Comment: have you ever tried to click on that small arrow in the log?

Comment: Are you using chrome?

Comment: At the end of the day the logs represent the same thing though. For example, refresh your page with the console closed, then open it up again, and you'll see that both logs are the same.

Comment: console.dir() for a consistent output.